# Утечки памяти при использовании CreateThread

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++

Я написал код

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD __stdcall MyThread(void*) {
    printf("Hello, Thread!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    HANDLE h = ::CreateThread(nullptr, 0, MyThread, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    ::WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
    ::CloseHandle(h);
}
```

а мне говорят что тут будут утечки памяти, и что надо использовать `_beginthread[ex]` или `std::thread`. Почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функции рантайма (CRT) хранят свое состояние в локальной памяти потока (Thread Local Storage, TLS). Это выглядит например так:

```
PerThreadData* ptd = TlsGetValue();
if (!ptd) {
  ptd = new PerThreadData;
  TlsSetValue(ptd);
}
```

При первом обращении к функции CRT, например к `printf` выделяется блок памяти под глобальные переменные CRT - `errno`, локали, и т.п. - всё, что уникально для потока.

Если поток создан с помощью `CreateThread`, как в коде в вопросе, то при выходе из потока TLS очищается, и вся выделенная память утекает.

По этому в Visual C++ существует функция `_beginthread`, которая оборачивает переданную ей функцию потока, так чтобы `PerThreadData` было удалено после завершения потока:

```
struct WrapperParams {
  void (*user_fn)(void*);
  void* user_arg;
};

DWORD __stdcall thread_fn_wrapper(WrapperParams* params) {
  params->user_fn(params->user_arg);
  delete params;

  PerThreadData* ptd = TlsGetValue();
  delete ptd;
}

uintptr_t _beginthread(void(*start_address)(void*),
                       unsigned stack_size,
                       void* arglist) {
  WrapperParams* params = new WrapperParams{start_address, arglist};
  HANDLE h = ::CreateThread(0, stack_size, thread_fn_wrapper, params, 0, 0);
  ::CloseHandle(h);
}
```

Класс `std::thread` также знает о блоке памяти CRT, и тоже чистит после себя память.

---

Примечание: для сопрограмм (fiber) вместо TLS используется FLS.

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните, определен ли список функций `CRT` которые используют локальное хранилище описанным вами способом, или от всех функций `CRT` следует ждать такого поведения.